# Data access layer for Cassandra cpp-driver in C++

Tags: c++, cassandra

Is there any Data Access Layer to re-use in my project that wraps the cpp-driver of the Cassandra? 
Or I have to directly use the Cassandra driver and create my own data layer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DataStax C/C++ driver for C*: https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I stated I am looking for a wrapper of Cassandra cpp-driver.